# Qlik Sense desktop: custom theme

Tags: qliksense

I have Qlik Sense Desktop installed and trying to create a custom theme based on 'highvis' theme that's built in. my question is that what is the directory should I put my theme in? please note that i am using desktop version which does not have XXX/Qlik/Sense/Client/themes as in server version.

also since we can access through localhost:4848/resource/theme/highvis/... i guess that those resource files are published to some directory, does anyone know the directory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The local theme folder is:

```
C:\Program Files\Qlik\Sense\Client\themes\SOMENEWTHEMENAMEFOLDER
```

then add the new theme name to the URL like you do with High Vis theme as described on this useful blog post:

http://webofwork.com/qlik-sense-high-vis-mode/

This is not a supported way of doing themes.

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it looks like this is the way to do theme on a server version but does not work my desktop version. and by the way, what's the best way to do custom theme ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty old post, but in case you need it for Qlik Sense 3 here is a good community post:
https://community.qlik.com/docs/DOC-13517

On Sense Server themes are found here
     C:\Program Files\Qlik\Sense\Client\themes

On Sense Dekstop (>= 3.0) themes are found here
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Qlik\Sense\Client\themes

Hope it helps, cheers!

Azucena